# How to invoke every array item when each array item is a function call

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, foreach

I have an array filled with function calls (i.e., `func(param);`) like this:

```js
var array = [
  func(param),
  func(param),
  func(param)
];
```

At some later point, I want to invoke all of those function calls at once. How can I do that?

I know that you can run a function on each item in an array with a for loop or forEach like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Or

```js
arrayName.forEach(function(e) {
  // do stuff
});
```

But I'm not sure how to code this so that it will do the invoking?

I have tried what follows, but I get the error "arrayName[i] is not a function."

```js
for (i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
  arrayName[i]();
}
```

EDIT: THREE SOLUTIONS

## 1: BEST, uses while loop

Here is the basic code:

```js
var soundsWaitingForNextBar = [];

while (soundsWaitingForNextBar.length > 0) {
  soundsWaitingForNextBar[0](); // call first item in array
  soundsWaitingForNextBar.shift(); // remove first item in array
}
```

Here is a more in depth version where items are pushed to the array every second but the array is only emptied every ten seconds:

```js
var soundsWaitingForNextBar = [];

function foo() {
  console.log('')
} // just making sure foo is a function

// pusing some functions into the array
soundsWaitingForNextBar.push(() => foo());
soundsWaitingForNextBar.push(() => foo());

setInterval(function() { // pushing items to array periodically to make sure the while loop is only emptying when it is called by setInterval and not every time an item is added to the array
  soundsWaitingForNextBar.push(() => foo());
}, 2000);


setInterval(function() {
  // this while loop does the magic: it calls and removes each item in the array
  while (soundsWaitingForNextBar.length > 0) {
    soundsWaitingForNextBar[0](); // call first item in array
    soundsWaitingForNextBar.shift(); // remove first item in array
  }
}, 10000);

setInterval(function() { // just checking to see how/when items are added to the array and emptied
  console.log('array.length: ' + soundsWaitingForNextBar.length);
}, 1000);
```

## 2: Uses `array[0]();` to call each array item/function.

```js
const func = console.log;
const param = 'foo';

const array = [
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param)
];

console.log(array.length); // just noting the original array length

arrayLength = array.length;
for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  array[0]();
  array.shift();
}

console.log(array.length); // just making sure the array is empty
```

## 3: Uses `array.forEach(fn => fn());` to call each array item/function.

```js
const func = console.log;
const param = 'foo';

const array = [
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param)
];

console.log(array.length); // just noting the original array length

array.forEach(fn => fn()); // calls each array item/function

arrayLength = array.length;
for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  array.shift();
}

console.log(array.length); // just making sure the array is empty
```

Note: in the for loop that I originally used to remove items from the array with `.splice`, I used `array.length`. For example: `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`. This didn't work (I'm not sure why) so I decided to determine the array length before the for loop using `arrayLength = array.length;`. Now the program works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
var array = [
  func(param),
  func(param),
  func(param)
];
```

you are *already* invoking those functions immediately, when the array is declared. It sounds like you want to defer their execution - you want them to be callable at *some point in the future*, not right now. instead, create an array of functions that, when called, call the function with the desired parameters, eg:

```
var array = [
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param)
];
```

Then, your `for` loop (or `forEach`) will work:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i]();
}
```

Demo:

```js
const func = console.log;
const param = 'foo';

const array = [
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param)
];
array.forEach(fn => fn());
```

You can also use `.bind` instead of a higher-order function:

```js
const func = console.log;
const param = 'foo';

const array = [
  func.bind(undefined, param),
  func.bind(undefined, param),
  func.bind(undefined, param)
];
array.forEach(fn => fn());
```

Comment: Amazing. I’ll give it a try and report back!

Comment: Your answer is the most clear to me. I did run into a new issue with your approach which I outlined in my post under "EDIT". I'd love to know if you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: When iterating through the array, do you want to call and remove the items that are added during iteration, or not?

Comment: The main goal is two-part. I want 1. all the items in the array to be called, and then 2. all of those called items to be removed from the array (so they won't be called again the next time this process happens). Each operation (calling, removing) could be done separately, but I'm thinking it would be smarter to call and remove each item one by one instead of calling every item and then later removing every item. If new items are added while this process is happening, they shouldn't be called this time, if possible. But that's an issue I can deal with later, I think.

Comment: I think I found two solutions. I'd be curious to know if you like them? I posted them above. I'm not sure if it's possible that new items can get added to my program while the for loop is in the process of calling, then removing, array items, but I haven't had an issue yet.

Comment: When exactly do additional items get pushed to the array? If pushing occurs when you call one of the functions in the array, then the `for` approach will run all functions, those in the array originally *and* those pushed during invocations. If additional items get pushed only *after* iterating through the array, then it would make more sense to discard the current array entirely, and declare another array that new functions get pushed to.

Comment: Items get pushed to the array more or less at random times. It is certainly possible that an item would get pushed to the array while the for loop is iterating through it. So, it sounds safest to use `array[0](); array.shift();` so that if an item is added to the array while the for loop is running, the new item is likely to also be called and then removed. it does look as though `.push` adds to the end of the array, which is good. since I am targeting [0] with `array[0]();` and `array.shift();`

Comment: The only problem is that I am using `arrayLength`, so the for loop won't include the added items as a result. I wonder if I can check and then update the `arrayLength` each cycle of the for loop? I'll have to test that now.

Comment: I decided to use a while loop. Solution added above. I think this is the best solution as I believe it will remove any added items while the loop is running.

Answer (score 1):

Because currently you're storing the return value of `func(param)`. Make each item a function reference to be able to call it later:

```
var array = [
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param)
];
```

Demo:

```js
function func(p) {
  console.log(p);
}

let param = "Parameter";

var array = [
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param),
  () => func(param)
];

array.forEach(e => e());
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need pass function name in array

```
var arrayName = [
  func,
  func,
  func
];
```

```js
function func(a){
return a*2;
};
var arrayName = [
  func,
  func,
  func
];

for (i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
  console.log(arrayName[i](2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is filled with `results` of `function calls` and not by `functions` the way you have it setup now. What you want to it store a function (anonymous or not) and execute it in your `for` loop.

You could also consider creating a function which to execute each of your functions and return an array with the results. For example you could [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through your array and since map returns an array as well you can have for each of your functions the actual result. Lets call the function `invokeMap` (similar to the [same exact function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#invokeMap) which `lodash` has):

```js
let add2 = x => x + 2

var fnArray = [  // array of anonymous functions
  (x) => x,  
  (x) => add2(x),
  (x) => add2(x) + add2(x)
];

let invokeMap = (arr, ...parrams) => arr.map((fn => fn(...parrams)))
 
let result = invokeMap(fnArray, 1) // pass one as a parameter to all functions

console.log(result)
```